Open new HTML page when clicked on the dynamically generated links
In my shiny app there is an output table with gene names in one column, I have added an extra column with links to some databases for each gene name, and the links are dynamic based on the name. In the simple app below you can see five genes (A to E) and for each gene I have the link for the gene's page on three different repository (Site 1 to 3).
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
          DT::DTOutput("myTable")
        )

server <- function(input, output) {

  table <- data.frame("Name" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
  
  output$myTable <- DT::renderDT({
  
  datatable(table %>%
    mutate("Links" = paste0("<a href='https://site1.com/", Name, "'>SITE1</a> - ",
                            "<a href='https://site2.com/", Name, "'>SITE2</a> - ",
                            "<a href='https://site3.com/", Name, "'>SITE3</a> - ")),
    rownames = F,
    escape = FALSE)
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The dummy app works fine as well as my actual app, the problem is that right now the user is redirected to the repository page and leaves the app when clicks on the links, while I need it to open a new tab instead and keep the original page. The closest solution I found on SO is this post where they change the target argument to "_blank", but unfortunately I could not make that work in my case as I'm making the links using a paste() command and I'm not sure how I can insert the target argument in that.

Try: paste0("<a href='https://site1.com/", Name, "' target='_blank'>SITE1</a> - ",                                     "<a href='https://site2.com/", Name, "'  target='_blank'>SITE2</a> - ",                                     "<a href='https://site3.com/", Name, "'  target='_blank'>SITE3</a> - ")
